# How can I tell Spotlight to consider RAW files as images

Tags: terminal, finder, spotlight

I would like to do a text search on my RAW files. The text search feature works very well with JPG, PNG... but it doesn't consider RAW files as images.

Is there a way to add the RAW extension (.ARW in my case) to the "Images" list ?

I tried everything with the finder. Terminal must be the rescue !

Comment: Are you referring to the the Live Text feature in macOS or are you searching for text within the filename?

Comment: @Allan The live text feature

Comment: RAW format is technically not an image file.  You have to think of it as the digital equivalent of a an undeveloped film negative (it’s also called a digital negative). For it to become an image it has to be processed into an image.  As far as whether or not Live Text can be made to process these RAW formats is what I don’t know as being possible.

Comment: I don't have anything that can shoot ARW, but our Ventura M1 iMac can "read" Nikon NEF files - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH7iK.jpg - I just took a photo of the screen here, quicklook,  selected some text & screenshot that. Now, whether technically it's reading the RAW or the embedded jpg, I cannot tell, but it reads it nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin and @Allan - I asked Bard / Chatgpt. They suggested this :
`defaults write com.apple.metadata:private.SpotlightV1 Kinds -array "ARW"` - I'm not very sure of that.
@Tetsujin : when you look at your file in the finder, on the "type column", does it says "Image NEF" ?

Comment: I wouldn't trust ChatGPT as far as I could spit it;) NEFs show as 'Nikon Electronic Format file'. I'm not sure how involved Spotlight is to this process. It's certainly not what's doing the reading, & this seems to say it doesn't index results completely - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429294/for-live-text-in-macos-monterey-can-you-have-it-scan-all-of-your-photos-and though it may be feature complete in Ventura. Can't test right now, our only Ventura Mac is in use by my partner ;)